# How can I fix the location of polkit and glib include headers?

Tags: compiling, polkit

I am developing an application in which I require to use PolicyKit and it appears PolicyKit uses Glib libraries. What happens is that I installed PolicyKit, but the location of the headers are on `/usr/include/polkit-1/` and `/usr/include/glib-2.0`.

and the headers have on their inside locations like
`/usr/include/`,
`/usr/include/polkit`,
`/usr/include/gobject`.

I can't compile because the compiler doesn't find the headers in the location the headers say they are supposed to be. I tried modifying each header individually, but its taking too long and I don't know when I'll be done.

The problem here is that when they are installed, they are installed in `/usr/include/polkit-1` and `/usr/include/glib-2.0` when they are supposed to be installed in `/usr/include` alone. In other words, the folder `polkit-1` and `glib-2.0` shouldn't be there. Anyone know of anyway to fix this quickly by putting the files and folders in their respective locations?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details, but some packages and libraries will install their files that way and also install files with their paths so that you can use `pkg-config` to find the correct paths.

I don't have `polkit`, but here, for `glib-2.0`, I can ask `pkg-config` to give me the "cflags" to use and compile with the library `glib-2.0` ("cflags" being flags to use with the C compiler, to specify include paths and libraries to add when linking):

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include  -lglib-2.0
```

I'd guess, for `polkit-1`, you'd do
    $ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 polkit-1

To compile with these parameters, either store them in variables in a makefile, copy their result or you can even just call `pkg-config` directly in the shell — as in the following example from the manpage:

```
cc program.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gnomeui)
```

(Actually, that example is a `Makefile` rule, but you can do it in the shell too.)

For some details, see the manpage, and check which `.pc` files are available under  `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`, `/usr/share/pkgconfig` and their `/usr/local` counterparts.

AFAIK, this is the portable way to compile with external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Giles's comment and think that the pkg_command from njsg is great.

Another common strategy to enable the link editor, ld, locate library files is to add their directories to the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the ld man page

from **man ld**

> ```
>      The linker uses the following search paths to locate required
>        shared libraries:
>
>        1.  Any directories specified by -rpath-link options.
>
>        2.  Any directories specified by -rpath options.  The difference
>            between -rpath and -rpath-link is that directories specified by
>            -rpath options are included in the executable and used at
>            runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at
>            link time. Searching -rpath in this way is only supported by
>            native linkers and cross linkers which have been configured
>            with the --with-sysroot option.
>
>        3.  On an ELF system, for native linkers, if the -rpath and
>            -rpath-link options were not used, search the contents of the
>            environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH".
>
>        4.  On SunOS, if the -rpath option was not used, search any
>            directories specified using -L options.
>
>        5.  For a native linker, the search the contents of the environment
>            variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".
> ```

Read the man page for further options.

Don't re-arrange packages.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks. I fixed it by doing this:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/include/polkit-1/polkit /usr/include/polkit
sudo cp -r /usr/include/polkit-1/polkitagent /usr/include/polkitagent
sudo cp -r /usr/include/polkit-1/polkitbackend /usr/include/polkitbackend
sudo cp -r /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio /usr/include/gio
sudo cp -r /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib /usr/include/glib
sudo cp -r /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject /usr/include/gobject
sudo cp -r /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h /usr/include/glib-object.h
sudo cp -r /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-unix.h /usr/include/glib-unix.h
sudo cp -r /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h /usr/include/glib.h
sudo cp -r /usr/include/glib-2.0/gmodule.h /usr/include/gmodule.h
```

If anyone have the same problem and use this, one must not delete the `glib-2.0` folder because its still going to be used.

Anyway now I'm missing `glibconfig.h` and its nowhere in the system. I don't know what to install to get it.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to do this. Don't change files under `/usr` (except under `/usr/local`), leave it for your distribution's package manager. If you're going to change stuff under `/usr`, which should be a last resort, at least use symbolic links: `cd /usr/include && sudo ln -s polkit-1/* glib-2.0/* .`. But the recommended option is to pass the proper `-I` directives when compiling. Or rather, to invoke `pkg-config`, which will take care of that.